# Excel Subset Data

Tags: excel, vlookup

SHEET1

```
STUDENT CLASS   INSTRUCTOR  SCORE
JOHN    A   1   49
JOHN    A   2   15
JOHN    B   1   94
MARY    A   1   23
MARY    B   2   32
KATE    C   3   76
KATE    D   1   73
KATE    D   1   56
KATE    D   2   7
KATE    C   7   71
JOE C   5   92
JOE D   1   94
```

SHEET2

```
STUDENT
MARY
JOE
```

DESIRE OUTPUT

```
STUDENT CLASS   INSTRUCTOR  SCORE
MARY    A   1   23
MARY    B   2   32
JOE C   5   92
JOE D   1   94
```

I have DATA on SHEET1 shown above and DATA on SHEET2 also above and I wish to create on SHEET3 the DESIRE OUTPUT

Basically take ALL THE DATA from SHEET1 but for only the STUDENT name listed in SHEET2. I try VLOOKUP with no success because there has more than 1 record for the names.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support `FILTER`?

Comment: @BigBen yes it has that function, I never use it before

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```vb
=FILTER(tblStudents, ISNUMBER(MATCH(tblStudents[STUDENT],tblFilter[STUDENT],0)))
```

Assuming that you named your table on sheet 1 "tblStudents" and the one on Sheet 2 "tblFilter":
[image]

If you want the header as well (and have the latest Excel 365) then you can use this formula:

```
=VSTACK(tblStudents[#Headers],
FILTER(tblStudents,ISNUMBER(MATCH(tblStudents[STUDENT],tblFilter[STUDENT],0))))
```